# Motor control with EVSPING34G4 none of the modes (Sensor-less, Quadrature, Hall) seems working

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am using ST Motor Control workbench to control a 30 pole bldc motor (hub wheel motor with encoder and hall feedback)

I have tried using instructions from:
https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32MotorControl:Frequently_Asked_Questions

to debug for sensor-less driving but it doesn't work.

1. In sensor-less mode I get startup failure after doing 1-2 turns
2. In quadrature encoder mode, it just vibrates sometimes
3. In Hall sensor mode I have speed feedback fault over.

Has anyone successfully worked on using a hub wheel motor with STM32 motor control boards? Any pointers that I could be missing?

Comment: What is the hardware you are working with? An evaluation board or a derived work?

Comment: Its the evaluation board EVSPING34G4

Comment: I can only find EVSPIN32G4. What supply voltage do you use and what motor parameters are known?

Comment: Yeah its EVSPIN32G4, sorry for typo. The motor params are known fully (from datasheet and from another off-the-shelf motor controller). Mot_type, torque_constant, B_Emf etc. are known.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?